# log4j parameterized logging

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to develop a simple logger which sends logs to a server where all the logs are stored and displayed in graphs, etc.

The logger has to be parameterized since there is a structure given by the developed database for analyzing and displaying the stored logs.

The parameters for the logs are implemented with overloaded methods, for example:

```
mylog.error(String jobname, String whatever);
mylog.error(String jobname, String whatever, List<String> whatever);
```

This is how the logs are implemented by a developer when needed.

I wonder if I could use log4j for something like this?

Anyway, my own simple logging works fine, sending the logs in json to my server, where they are stored, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is how [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) works. Decouple logging from your application with SLF4J and you can use the Log4J connector to use it as the underlying implementation. That being said, the creator of SLF4J wrote [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) to be an ideal implementation of the SLF4J interface. If you aren't tied organizationally to Log4J, I suggest you use it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this.

I tend to prefer a [Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC)](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) (and [comparison with NDC](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/NDCvsMDC)) although I wrote my own formatter extension for displaying it as I needed ordered rendering.

Other frameworks have similar capabilities, but a mapped approach allows for some nice headings, which is handy for log parsing tools, or for DB-oriented logging.

Comment: do you have maybe an example for this. could it be possible to log like this, using the log4j :  private static final Logger log = Logger.....      log.error(String string) <- standard logging and here my addition overloaded error method: mylog.error(String string, String whatever);
 log.error(String string, String whatever, List<String> whatever) but the

Comment: @core2hack Example of what? There are examples of using an MDC on the web, like [this one](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/).